# Creating an Array of Id's

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array, `var players = ['', '', '', '', '', ''];`. Now I want that array to contain 6 items from a list:

```
    <ul id="Available Players">
        <li id="node7">Player A</li>
        <li id="node8">Player B</li>
        <li id="node9">Player C</li>
        <li id="node10">Player D</li>
        <li id="node11">Player E</li>
        <li id="node12">Player F</li>
    </ul>
```

Now, I want the array to look kinda like this:
`var players = [.node7, .node8, .node9, .node10, .node11, .node12];`. Also, if I were to create a new array called `round1`, can I get the values of the first 4 values from the `players` array? It should look somewhat similar to this: `var round1 = [players[0], players[1], players[2], players[3]];`

So how can I do all of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following approach.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('Available Players'), //get the 'ul' element
    round1 = [], // create 'round1' array
    players = Array.from(parent.children).map(function(v){ //get all the 'li' elements
      return "." + v.id; //return 'id' attribute of every 'li' element 
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){ // push only four first elements from 'players' array 
      round1.push(players[i]); // to the 'round1' array
    }
    
    console.log(players); //reveal the results
    console.log(round1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul id="Available Players">
  <li id="node7">Player A</li>
  <li id="node8">Player B</li>
  <li id="node9">Player C</li>
  <li id="node10">Player D</li>
  <li id="node11">Player E</li>
  <li id="node12">Player F</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Quick question - what is the `.as-console-wrapper` css rule for?

Comment: @aberkow It changes the default `height` setting of the code snippet's console. As you can see now, the console takes 100% of the snippet height.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the node of the parent id, and then all list elements and extract the id.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementById('Available Players').getElementsByTagName('li'),
    ids = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(a) {
        return '.' + a.getAttribute('id');
    }),
    round1 = ids.slice(0, 4);
  
console.log(ids);
console.log(round1);
```

```html
<ul id="Available Players">
  <li id="node7">Player A</li>
  <li id="node8">Player B</li>
  <li id="node9">Player C</li>
  <li id="node10">Player D</li>
  <li id="node11">Player E</li>
  <li id="node12">Player F</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `element.children` property to get a list of every `li` inside your `ul`, and then use `Array#map` to get their `id`. Then, use `players.slice(0, 4)` to get your `round1` players.

It is unclear from your question whether you want `players` to hold the names of each player, the `li` elements themselves, or the `id` of each `li` element. Here is how you would get all three:

```js
var nodes = [].slice.call(
  document.getElementById('Available Players').children
)

function prop (o) { return o[this] }

var nodeIds = nodes.map(prop, 'id')

var playerNames = nodes.map(prop, 'textContent')

console.log(nodes)
console.log(nodeIds)
console.log(playerNames)

var players = nodeIds // or whichever array above you meant

var round1 = players.slice(0, 4)

console.log(round1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<ul id="Available Players">
  <li id="node7">Player A</li>
  <li id="node8">Player B</li>
  <li id="node9">Player C</li>
  <li id="node10">Player D</li>
  <li id="node11">Player E</li>
  <li id="node12">Player F</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="available-players">
  <li id="node7">Player A</li>
  <li id="node8">Player B</li>
  <li id="node9">Player C</li>
  <li id="node10">Player D</li>
  <li id="node11">Player E</li>
  <li id="node12">Player F</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var players = [];
var li = document.querySelectorAll('#available-players li');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  players.push(li[i].getAttribute('id'));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var players=[];  
  var round1=[];  
  var items=$("#Available_Players li")  
   items.each(function(){  
    console.log($(this));  
    players.push('.'+$(this)[0].id);
   });

  round1 = players.slice(0, 4);  
  console.log(players);  
  console.log(round1);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PxvzROhFotj0p4UKMCC4?p=preview